# Wake on lan doesn't work when DisplayPort cable is connected

Tags: hdmi, displayport, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to configure wake on lan on my Windows 10 desktop and I've discovered that wake on lan doesn't work if there's a DisplayPort cable plugged in (I have tried 3 different DP cables), it works fine when there is only an HDMI cable plugged in. The issue is I only have 1 DisplayPort on my graphics card and I ideally need 2 monitors for my work. I have tried searching for solutions but unable to find any, do I have to buy a graphics card with 2 HDMI ports?